# Gradlew - Invalid JAVA_HOME path, when is is correct

Tags: gradle, gradlew

I'm trying to build libGDX project but gradlew just stopped working. Two months ago it worked fine. It seems that updating Java broke it. Here is what happens:

[image: 1]]
 and here are contents of Java folder(don't know why would it be useful):

[image: 2]]

Comment: jdk= java development kit ;jre= java run environment. so change path to jre

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `JAVA_HOME` variable is pointing to the `jdk1.8.0_101` directory, but it (according to the screenshot in your question) use to be `jre1.8.0_101` (it's JRE, not JDK).

Though, you probably need JDK to build something, not JRE, so just check one more time, whether you have JDK installed in the directory `JAVA_HOME` pointing to.